# Selecting a suitable mosfet for Linear Technology LTC4412HV

Tags: power, mosfet, power-electronics

I would like to choose a suitable P-MOSFET for power switching with the [Linear Technology LTC4412HV](http://cds.linear.com/docs/Datasheet/4412hvfs.pdf).
This IC is just an ORing for two power supplies to select the best between two batteries.

The [FDN306P](http://morrow.ece.wisc.edu/IEEE/2010/Datasheets/Fairchild/FDN306P.pdf) in the typical application can just stand \$V_{DS}\$ of 12V, and current 2A. I would like to have a \$V_{DS}\$ of 40V, and 7A at least. I have googled around but I'm worried that there are other factors that I should consider.

Also, how much is the resistor that is needed for the required parameters? The datasheet of the IC doesn't say much about that.

Comment: Ask your Linear sales representative's FAE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That little controller is doing a pretty good job.  The reason why the datasheet doesn't give much information, is that the tag line "almost any FET" really is true here, there really isn't much to consider.

Other factors that you need to check:

1. is whether or not it drives the gate properly (and excedes threshold )-> checked it and it either drives 0 volts or - 7 V.  Most PMOS power FET's thresholds are lower magnitude.
2. Gate capacitance could be an issue with the power cut over if the device has limited drive current and the higher capacitance slows it down.  But given high threshold devices (typical) this should be OK.  But read through the datasheet.

The datasheet indicates that the control output sinks 10uA, using ohms law and the voltage that you need to connect to you can calculate the value of the pull-up resistor yourself.  For example if you are driving a 5V signal:

\$ \frac{5 V}{10 uA}= 500 k\Omega \$

There is no resistors on the sense input! from page 8 of the datasheet
[image]

Comment: would you just give a good mosfet smd example please :) ? and what about the resistor ?

Comment: http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf7240pbf.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I wish be a good engineer like you in the future :).